# How to search CharField in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, orm

I want to do a search feature: I use `GodX` to register my username in user management after I search `godx` as username keyword, I can get the `GodX` object.

Currently I am limited to do the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = user.objects.get(username="godx")
# I hope I can get `GodX` object but the method is unavailable.
```

How do I do?

Answer (score 2):

I find answer by myself!

According to these links from django document:

[Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)

[iexact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-iexact)

If I use `iexact`:

```
>>> Blog.objects.get(name__iexact="beatles blog")
```

It would match a Blog titled "Beatles Blog", "beatles blog", or even "BeAtlES blOG".

And the SQL equivalents:

```
SELECT ... WHERE name ILIKE 'beatles blog';
```

So, I can get I expect.